# javascript Image Data Object to Image Object (Trying to fill() with image data)

Tags: javascript, html, getimagedata, putimagedata

What i am trying to do is context.createImageData(xxx,xxx) then take that image data and manipulate it, then context.createPattern(imagedata, 'repeat') with the image data to fill in my drawn object with the image data that I procedural made. The problem that I am having is createPattern takes in a Image Object not a Image Data Object. So I need to either find out a way of converting a Image Data Object to a Image Object or be given a better way to fill() with a procedural generated images.

thanks for your help!!